# Last 3 digits of $7^{12341}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that I need to reduce $7^{12341} \pmod {1000}$

By Euler I have $7^{\phi(1000)}\equiv 7^{400}\equiv1\pmod{1000}$

That leaves me with the monster $7^{341}\pmod{1000}$

Is there a way to reduce this smoothly without working $7^2, 7^4, 7^8$ etc manually ?

Comment: You have $341 = 11*31$.

Comment: A Bit calculations gives me $007$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$7^{20}=(7^5)^4=((16807)^2)^2\equiv((807)^2)^2\equiv(651249)^2\equiv249^2\equiv62001\equiv1\pmod {1000}
$

 Then we write $7^{341}=7*(7^{20})^{17}\equiv7*1^{17}\equiv7\pmod {1000}$

Comment: wow!may I know how to know 20 gives 1 ? I thought we can only figure out that 400 gives 1 by euler theorem

Comment: i mean how does one guess 20 is the magic number ?

Comment: @rsadhvika $7 \equiv -1 \pmod 8$ so it is easy to see that any even exponent satisfies the $2$-adic part of the congruence.  For the $5$-adic part, we easily observe that $7^2 = 49 \equiv -1 \pmod{25}$, so then $7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{25}$, and an easy application of binomial theorem shows that $(7^4)^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks! hope all these cool ideas come to me in exam :)

Comment: @rsadhvika, Using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function, $$7^{12341}\equiv7^{41}\pmod{1000}$$

Answer (score 2):

To find $7^{341} (\bmod 1000)$, it suffices to work out $7^{341} (\bmod 125)$ and $7^{341} (\bmod 8)=-1$. The former can be done with successive squaring, as you mentioned.

Comment: Note also that $\varphi(125)=100$, so you really just need $7^{41} (\bmod 125)$.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry this doesn't seem to answer my question: How to reduce  $7^{341}\pmod{5^3}$ without working successive squares ?

Comment: Oh nice :) so we're left with $7^{41}\pmod{125}$

Comment: actually I am curious to find if there is a way to work $a \pmod{p^n}$ if we know $a\pmod{p}$. Because finding $a \pmod{p}$ is easy, but I feel there should be some way to work $a \pmod{p^n}$ using the result $a\pmod{p}$ ?

Comment: That is a useful question.  Experiment with a=2 mod5,25,125,625 then a=7,12,17 conjecture, test, try to prove

Answer (score 2):

$$7^2=50-1$$

$$7^{20n+1}=7(7^2)^{10n}$$

Now $(7^2)^{10n}=(50-1)^{10n}=(1-50)^{10n}$

Using Binomial Theorem,
$(7^2)^{10n}=1-\binom{10n}150+\binom{10n}2(50)^2\cdots+(50)^{2n}$

$\implies(7^2)^{10n}\equiv1-500n+\dfrac{10n(10n-1)}250^2\pmod{1000}\ \ \ \ (1)$ for $n\ge2$

Again, $\dfrac{10n(10n-1)}250^2=50n^2(50^2)-5n(2500)\equiv-500n\pmod{1000}$ as $2500\equiv100\pmod{200}\implies5(50^2)\equiv5\cdot100\pmod{5\cdot200}\equiv500$

From $(1),$

$(7^2)^{10n}\equiv1-500n-500n\pmod{1000}\equiv1$

Here $n=\dfrac{12341 -1}{20}$

Answer (score 1):

As you simplified it till $7^{341}$ (mod 1000);

from there => $7^{341}$ = $7^{340}$*$7^{1}$
                        = $7^{4(85)}$*$7^{1}$
                        = $2401^{85}$*$7^{1}$

so last three digits of $2401^{85}$*$7^{1}$ = last three digits of product of the last three digits of $2401^{85}$ and $7^{1}$

As we know the last digit of $7^{1}$ = 7;

To calculate the last three digits of $2401^{85}$ it we use last three digits of the no 2401 i.e, 401.

last two digits of any power of a number ending with 01 gives 01 only and the third last digit will be the units digit in 4*85 or simply 4*5 i.e, 0

So the last three digits of $2401^{85}$ are 001.

And the last three digits of the original number $7^{12341}$ will be 001*7 = **007**.

Comment: I missed that.. a very useful observation, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If $7^n \equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$ then $7^{-1} \equiv 7^{n-1} \pmod{1000}$.

Solving $7x \equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$ we find that $x \equiv 143 \pmod{1000}$.

If we perform $\pmod{10}$ calculations on $7^n, n \ge 1$ we get

$$ 7,9,3,1,7,9,3 \dots$$

Since this is of period $4$ we are looking for the first $k \ge 1$ where

$$ 7^3 \cdot (7^4)^k \equiv 143 \pmod{1000}$$

Now $7^3 \equiv 343 \pmod{1000}$ and $7^4 \equiv 401 \pmod{1000}$ and

$\; (300 + 43) * (400 + 1) \equiv 300 + 200 + 43 \equiv 543 \pmod{1000}$
$\; (500 + 43) * (400 + 1) \equiv 500 + 200 + 43 \equiv 743 \pmod{1000}$
$\; (700 + 43) * (400 + 1) \equiv 700 + 200 + 43 \equiv 943 \pmod{1000}$
$\; (900 + 43) * (400 + 1) \equiv 900 + 200 + 43 \equiv 143 \pmod{1000}$

So $k = 4$ gets us to the inverse $7^{-1} \equiv 7^{19} \pmod{1000}$ and therefore

$$ 7^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{1000}$$

We can take the last line of Antony's answer to wrap this up.