# Find the remainder when $7^{7^{7}}$ is divided by 1000

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with this problem please

> Find the remainder when $7^{7^{7}}$ is divided by $1000$

My try follow

$1000=8×125$ , now

$7 \equiv -1 \;\bmod\; (8)$ 
$\to$  $7^{7^{7}} \equiv -1 \;\bmod\; (8)$      and

$7^{100}\equiv 1 \;\bmod\; (125)$

Any help to complete this solution?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430633/calculating-7777777-mod-100  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983926/last-3-digits-of-712341/983943   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781

Answer (score 3):

Since $7^4=2\,401\equiv1\pmod{400}$ and since $7^3=343$, $7^7\equiv343\pmod{400}$. So, by Fermat-Euler, $7^{7^7}\equiv7^{343}\pmod{1\,000}$.

Since $7^4\equiv401\pmod{1\,000}$, $7^{20}=(7^4)^5\equiv1\pmod{1\,000}$. Therefore$$7^{343}=7^{340+3}\equiv7^3=343\pmod{1\,000}.$$

Comment: How are you able to switch from mod 400 to mod 1000. What makes this possible?

Comment: I used the fact that $\varphi(1000)=400$. It follows from this and from the [Fermat-Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) that, if $b\equiv c\pmod{400}$, and if $a$ and $1000$ are coprime, then $a^b\equiv a^c\pmod{1000}$.

Comment: oh, thank you. I have never heard of Fermat-Euler theorem. Do you know where I can learn more about it (link)? And what is the symbol phi?

Comment: I've added a link to my previous comment.

Comment: This question appears on Purplecomet 2017 middle school division Problem 15 (https://purplecomet.org/contestApi/downloadpracticecontests/index.php?contest_id=25&language_id=374) . Is it expected that a middle schooler competing for this contest will know this way of doing the problem? How could a middle school student do this problem with the tools they have?

Comment: Perhaps not, but they can do it [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2353319/446262).

Answer (score 1):

As $7^4=2400+1$  and $7\equiv-1\pmod4\implies 7^7\equiv-1\equiv3\pmod4$

We can write $7^7=4m+3$ where integer $m\ge0$

$$7^{4m+3}=7^3(1+2400)^m$$

Now $(1+2400)^m\equiv1+\binom m12400\pmod{1000}$

$7^8=(1+2400)^2\equiv1\pmod{40}\implies7^7\equiv7^{-1}\equiv23$

We can choose $7^7=40n+23=4(10n+5)+3$

$\implies m\equiv5\pmod{10}, m=10r+5$(say)

$1+2400m\equiv1+2400(10r+5)\equiv1\pmod{1000}$

Answer (score 1):

$(7^{100} \mod 125)= 1$ so $7^{7^7} = 7^{(7^7 \bmod 100)} \mod 125 = 7^{43} \mod 125 = 93$

Now you can use Chinese remainder theorem with $x = 93 \pmod {125}$ and $x = -1 \pmod 8$, fastest way by hand is to check the $8$ values of $125 + 93k$ in the range of $0$ to $1000$ to see which one is $-1$ of $\pmod 8$.

---

Alternatively

$$\begin{align}
%
7 \text{^} (7 \text{^}  7) \mod 1000 & = 
%
7 \text{^} (7 \text{^}  7 \mod \Phi 1000) \mod 1000 \\
%
&= 7 \text{^} (7 \text{^}  7 \mod 400) \mod 1000 \\
%
&= 7 \text{^} 343 \mod 1000 \\
%
&= 343 \\
%
\end{align}$$

Just calculating $7 \text{^} 823543 \pmod {1000}$ is trivial with modular exponentiation as well.

Comment: thank you for your help,  can you elaborate this step please    $7^{43} \mod 125 = 93$

Comment: Just modular exponentiation.  Eventually you do have to do some arithmetic.  I suspect there is some trick to this problem in $7^{7^3} \equiv 7^3 \pmod {1000}$ that creates a shortcut.  Dunno off the top of my head though.  The numbers are so small that any tricks are really a waste of time.