# Showing that a number ends in 007

Tags: number-theory

Find a positive integer x such that the last three
digits of $7^{7^x} $ are 007 (do not use trial and error) 
i mean clearly when $x=1$ the number is divisible by 7 i believe that every $x\in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by 7 as mod 7 it always 0 but ending by 007 and being divisible by 7 are different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the remainder when $7^{7^{7}}$ is divided by 1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353314/find-the-remainder-when-777-is-divided-by-1000)

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that there is a method here besides trial and error? [Discrete logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) are notoriously difficult to compute.

Comment: A possible answer is $x=4$, following the duplicate.

Comment: How much would it help you if I told you that ending with 007 is the same thing as being equal to 7 modulo 1000?

Comment: @DietrichBurde how did you get that from your duplicate?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom lab starts his answer: "As $7^ 4=2400+1$" etc.

Comment: You probably need to use _some_ trial and error, but if you know the Chinese remainder theorem and Fermat's little theorem, things become a lot easier.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ah, should have looked closer.  Thank you.

Comment: you may try binomial here...and 007 ...reminds one of james bond right:)

Comment: $7^{7^4} \equiv 7 \mod 1000$ therefore it ends by $007$. Please notice that $7^{7^4}$ is a number composed by $2\,030$ digits. $7^{7^8}$ ends by $007$, too (about 5 million digits) and $7^{7^{12}}$ about ten billion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number $N$ ends with $007$ iff $N \equiv 7 \bmod 1000$.

We have $7^n \equiv 7 \bmod 1000$ iff $7^{n-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 1000$.

Now the order of $7 \bmod 1000$ is $20$. Therefore,  $7^n \equiv 7 \bmod 1000$ iff $20$ divides $n-1$.

For $n=7^x$, we want to know when $7^x \equiv 1 \bmod 20$.

Now the order of $7 \bmod 20$ is $4$. Therefore,  $7^x \equiv 1 \bmod 20$ iff $4$ divides $x$.